# Complicated string replacement in files

Tags: string, bash, awk, replace, sed

So, I have some strings to replace in some data files for a game I'm working on. I'm fine with using either `sed` or `awk`. I need help programming the bash script to replace this, so here's a list of things I want to replace. (Keep in mind that I will be using X in brackets in place of numbers, also, for strings 1 and 2 there is a space after the string I need to replace, which I need to replace the space as well.)

1. Replace every instance of `\\P[x]:` with `\\n<\\P[x]>\\pf[x]`
2. Replace every instance of `\\N[x]:` with `\\n<\\N[x]>\\af[x]`
3. Replace every instance of `"volume":80` with `"volume":90`
4. Replace every instance of `...` with `\\..\\..\\..\\.`
5. Replace every instance of `"]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":["` with `"]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":["` (There is a space at the beginning of the string I need to replace, I want to move that to the end of the string.)

Here's what I have tried:

```
sed -e 's/"volume":80/"volume":90/g' -e 's///g' -e 's/\ \"]},{\"code\":401,\"indent\":0,\"parameters\":[\"/\"]},{\"code\":401,\"indent\":0,\"parameters\":[\"\ /g' < ${file} > ${outdir}/${filename}.${extension}
```

I get this error: `sed: -e expression #3, char 109: unterminated s' command

And here's a script I created, can't figure out how to get it to work right:

```
#!/bin/bash
direct=./1
outdir=./2
mkdir -p $direct
mkdir -p $outdir
for file in ${direct}/*.*; do
  filepath=$(basename "$file")
  extension="${filepath##*.}"
  filename="${filepath%.*}"
  strb='"volume":80'
  strr='"volume":90'
  echo 1 && sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
  strb='...'
  strr='\\..\\..\\..\\.'
  echo 2 && sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
  num=0
  while [ "$num" -le "99" ]; do
    strb='\\P['"$num"']\: '
    strr='\\n<\\P['"$num"']>\\pf['"$num"']'
    sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
    strb='\\N['"$num"']\: '
    strr='\\n<\\N['"$num"']>\\af['"$num"']'
    sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
    num=$(echo $num+1 | bc -l)
  done
  strb=' "]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":["'
  strr='"]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":[" '
  echo 5 && sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
  strb='Move1'
  strr='Move'
  echo 6 && sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
  strb='Move'
  strr='Move1'
  echo 7 && sed -e "s#\"${strb}\"#\"${strr}\"#g" -i ${file}
  echo ${filename}.${extension}
done
```

On the fifth instance of sed, I get `unterminated s' command`

Comment: This might be a little tedious, but it's actually simple. Did you lookup the substitute command of `sed`?

Comment: SO is for help with programming, not a place to request others write your code for you. Please improve your question with some code that you've tried, your input and output samples, and any relevant error messages.

Comment: @CodeGnome added the script

Comment: When you were asked if you had looked up the substitute command of sed and you glibly said `nope` that attitude and lack of effort turned a lot of people off trying to help you, hence the downvotes and close votes. Why did you say you hadn't bothered to look into it when had already written a script using it? It might be too late now but if you [edit] your question again to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we would have the necessary information to start trying to help you (if anyone's still looking at this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get `unterminated s' command` on the fifth instance of `sed` in your script because your `s'` command is terminated with double-quotes, but your `$strb` and `$strr` strings also have unescaped double quotes in them. This is a problem for your entire script, but luckily, the fifth instance happens to have an odd number of double quotes, causing a syntax error and revealing the problem. Since none of your strings have single-quotes, using only single-quotes to terminate `sed` and wrapping all of your variables in double-quotes to preserve their literals is a safe bet, e.g.,

```
sed -e 's#'"${strb}"'#'"${strr}"'#g' -i ${file}
```

You also have some `[]` and some `.` in your strings. These have a special meaning to sed, so you should escape those (for the pattern, not the replacement), e.g.,

change

```
strb='...'
```

to

```
strb='\.\.\.'
```

and change

```
strb=' "]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":["'
```

to

```
 strb=' "\]},{"code":401,"indent":0,"parameters":\["'
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33005/65267 for more on characters with special meaning to `sed`.